# What is the meaning of dot words in cards game?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In **[The Bug's Life](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120623/)**, Dot & his friends playing cards game with bug which is recovering from leg injury.

In Middle of the Game, dot say this words to Bug.

> Ah-ah-ah. Read 'em and weep.

What does it means?

Comment: Did you look up [read 'em and weep](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Read-Em-and-Weep.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just go through your whole answer, if it's all the same to you. I don't mean anything by it—good on you for coming here and asking questions—but fixing some of the other mistakes is much more important than the answer to the question.

> What is the meaning of **Dot's** words in **this card** game?
>
> In **[*A Bug's Life*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120623/)**, Dot & his friends **are** playing **a card** game with **a** bug **who** is recovering from **a** leg injury.
>
> In **the middle** of the **game**, **Dot says these** words to **the bug:**
>
> > Ah-ah-ah. Read 'em and weep.
>
> What does **that mean**?

Mostly, you need to work on getting ahold of proper nouns (names) versus common nouns (things and general descriptions) and countable things versus uncountable stuff.

Anyway, *'em* is informal English for *them*; he's talking about the cards he's laying down across the bug's chest; and he's saying his cards are better than the cards the other players thought were a winning hand.

It's an expression from poker but you may see it other places, too. Another person saying it to you is why you shouldn't count your eggs before they've hatched.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a common phrase](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Read-Em-and-Weep.html), meaning he (believes, anyway) has the winning hand in the game. It suggests that when the others *read* his cards, they will *weep* because they have lost.